# SpringBoot Import Issue : org.bouncycastle.openssl

Tags: spring, openssl, bouncycastle

I need help about Spring import.

I want to import 'import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser'.

In my build.gradle, there is "implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70'"

All references use PEMParser, but i can't import it.

Just in Case for you Understanding, I put pictures about my build.gradle.
Thank you for reading this. Have a nice day.!

Search many of Googles
change the version of library
invalidate the cache in intellij

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.9'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'tellingme'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:20.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:20.1.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    runtimeOnly 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.maricn:logback-slack-appender:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.2.2'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70'
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as images, instead include your `build.gradle` as code.

Comment: For starters stop mixing modules from different versions of a framework. In this case Spring Boot. You are mixing 2.5.9 and 2.7.5. Remove the version from the `spring-boot-starter-security`. Next to that I believe Spring Boot manages the bouncycastle version so you should/could remove that as well.

Comment: Oh i got it thank you for your kindness..
i removed the security version -> "implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'"

but still can't import bouncycastle..

Comment: I think you need an additional bouncycastle dependency as well, the `bcpkix-jdk15on` module as you currently only have the providers not the utilities.